# Matching (and summing) many fields to one in R

Tags: r

I have a data file (.csv) where each observation is one of 333 districts. Each district has an ID like 1101, 1102, ... .  Second, I have another data file (.csv) where each observation is one of 112,975 towns, including  population data. The town data has a district_ID field. There are around 300 towns per district. So, there is one district with `district_ID == 1101` and about 300 towns with `district_ID == 1101`.

I want to create a district-level population variable in my district dataset. This means matching multiple town observations to each single district observation, and summing the town-level populations.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A data.table solution:

```
#some example data
set.seed(42)
districts <- data.frame(district_ID=1:10,whatever=rnorm(10))
towns <- data.frame(town=1:100,district_ID=rep(1:10,each=10),
                    population=rpois(100,sample(c(1e3,1e4,1e5))))

library(data.table)
districts <- data.table(districts,key="district_ID")
towns <- data.table(towns,key="district_ID")

#calculate district population
temp <- towns[,list(district_pop=sum(population)),by=district_ID]
#merge result with districts data.table
districts <- merge(districts,temp)

#    district_ID    whatever district_pop
# 1:           1  1.37095845       434886
# 2:           2 -0.56469817       334084
# 3:           3  0.36312841       342241
# 4:           4  0.63286260       433224
# 5:           5  0.40426832       334039
# 6:           6 -0.10612452       342810
# 7:           7  1.51152200       433362
# 8:           8 -0.09465904       333810
# 9:           9  2.01842371       342035
# 10:          10 -0.06271410       432302
```

Comment: How could I generalize this to sum all columns in `towns`, not just one (above, population), indexed by `district_ID`?

Comment: `temp <- towns[,lapply(.SD, sum),by=district_ID]` possibly also using `.SDcols`. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Benchmark with larger dataset.

Compute the populations of each district using tapply function:

```
districtdata$population<-
  tapply(towndata$population,towndata$district_ID,sum)[districts$district_ID]
```

Some benchmarking, just for fun:

```
fn1<-function(districts,towns) 
{
  districts$population<-
       tapply(towns$population,towns$district_ID,sum)[districts$district_ID]

  districts
}
fn2<-function(districts,towns) #Roland's data.table approach:
{ 
  districts <- data.table(districts,key="district_ID")
  towns <- data.table(towns,key="district_ID")
  temp<-towns[,list(district_pop=sum(population)),by=district_ID]
  merge(districts,temp)
}



set.seed(42)
districts <- data.frame(district_ID=1:300,whatever=rnorm(300))
towns <- data.frame(town=1:100000,district_ID=rep(1:300,each=300),
                    population=rpois(300000,sample(c(1e3,1e4,1e5))))

microbenchmark(fn1(districts,towns),fn2(districts,towns))
Unit: milliseconds
                  expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 fn1(districts, towns) 215.29266 231.47103 243.72353 265.28280 355.43895   100
 fn2(districts, towns)  20.03636  27.51046  36.11116  58.56448  88.70766   100
```

Comment: @Roland yes I agree, changed the benchmark. I'm bit suprised that `tapply` is so much slower.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
aggregate(population ~ district_ID, towns, sum)
```

(based on Roland's synthetic data)